# How to smooth 'zoom' and 'pan' of image in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-animate

I am using ActionScript 3 in Adobe Animate to zoom and pan for drawings. Whenever the center button in the control panel is clicked, the image doesn't appear in the center, it appears a bit right below..

[Example of how photo inside MovieClip is not centred to the stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnIst.jpg).

[image]

Also, the pan and zoom are not smooth. The code that I am using is creating a video clip of image and there is a control panel to control the zoom and pan. Please let me know the changes required to make it smooth and workable.

The AS3 code is given below:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var moveSpeed: Number = 5;
var sizeScale: Number = 0.04;
var clickMore: Boolean = false;
var clickLess: Boolean = false;
var clickLeft: Boolean = false;
var clickRight: Boolean = false;
var clickUp: Boolean = false;
var clickDown: Boolean = false;
var clickCenter: Boolean = false;
```

// --- Click Zoom more:

```
btMore.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moreZoom);
function moreZoom(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickMore = true;
}
btMore.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMoreZoom);
function stopMoreZoom(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickMore = false;
}
```

// --- Click Zoom less:

```
btLess.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, lessZoom);
function lessZoom(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickLess = true;
}
btLess.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopLessZoom);
function stopLessZoom(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickLess = false;
}
```

// --- Click Move left:

```
btLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, leftMove);
function leftMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickLeft = true;
}
btLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopLeftMove);
function stopLeftMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickLeft = false;
}
```

// --- Click Move right:

```
btRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, rightMove);
function rightMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickRight = true;
}
btRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopRightMove);
function stopRightMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickRight = false;
}
```

// --- Click Move up:

```
btUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, upMove);
function upMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickUp = true;
}
btUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopUpMove);
function stopUpMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickUp = false;
}
```

// --- Click Move Down:

```
btDown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downMove);
function downMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickDown = true;
}
btDown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDownMove);
function stopDownMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickDown = false;
}
```

// --- Click Move Center:

```
btCenter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, centerMove);
function centerMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickCenter = true;
}
btCenter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopCenterMove);
function stopCenterMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 clickCenter = false;
}
```

// --- Click Zoom Wheel:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
function handleMouseWheel(event: MouseEvent): void {
 if (myMCimg.scaleX >= 1) {
 myMCimg.scaleX += (event.delta * sizeScale);
 myMCimg.scaleY += (event.delta * sizeScale);
 } else {
 myMCimg.scaleX = 1;
 myMCimg.scaleY = 1;
 }
}
```

// --- Actions:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
function enterFrame(event: Event): void {
 if (clickMore == true) {
 myMCimg.scaleX += sizeScale;
 myMCimg.scaleY += sizeScale;
 }
 if ((clickLess == true) && (myMCimg.scaleX >= 1)) {
 myMCimg.scaleX -= sizeScale;
 myMCimg.scaleY -= sizeScale;
 }
 if (clickLeft == true) {
 myMCimg.x -= moveSpeed;
 }
 if (clickRight == true) {
 myMCimg.x += moveSpeed;
 }
 if (clickUp == true) {
 myMCimg.y -= moveSpeed;
 }
 if (clickDown == true) {
 myMCimg.y += moveSpeed;
 }
 if (clickCenter == true) {
```

// --- Centralize:

```
 myMCimg.scaleX = 1;
 myMCimg.scaleY = 1;
 myMCimg.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
 myMCimg.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
 }
}
```

// --- Click keys directions keyboard:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressKeys);
function pressKeys(event: KeyboardEvent): void {

 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
 myMCimg.x -= moveSpeed;
 }
 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
 myMCimg.x += moveSpeed;
 }
 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
 myMCimg.y -= moveSpeed;
 }
 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
 myMCimg.y += moveSpeed;
 }
 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) {
```

// --- Centralize:

```
 myMCimg.scaleX = 1;
 myMCimg.scaleY = 1;
 myMCimg.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
 myMCimg.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
 }
```

// --- Click Drag:

```
 myMCimg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragMove);
 function dragMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 myMCimg.startDrag();
}
 myMCimg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragMove);
 function stopDragMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
 stopDrag();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Centralize :

To centralize by width (horizontal), try also subtracting by half-width of picture like:

```
myMCimg.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (myMCimg.width / 2);
```

Same logic for centralizing by height (vertical).

(2) Zoom :

As for smooth zoom, I haven't tested your code so not sure what the visual problem *"not smooth"* means exactly. Maybe it's your output settings? In your **Publish Settings** (press `Ctrl+Shift+F12`) does *"smoothness"* improve if you try those 3 **Hardware Acceleration** options: None, Direct and GPU?

Finally, I can only suggest you try something like this below as an alternative (maybe it helps) :

To test the code...

- Create 2 different colour boxes on stage.
- Convert each box to MovieClip (not as Button).
- Give each box an *instance* name (example: `zoom_in` and `zoom_out`).
- Add/convert image into some MovieClip with *instance* name `pic`.

First example will update zoom via mouse roll-over...

```
zoom_in.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, process_zoom_rollover);
zoom_in.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, process_zoom_rollout);

zoom_out.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, process_zoom_rollover);
zoom_out.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, process_zoom_rollout);

//# mouse pointer is placed over either zoom-in or zoom-out icon..
function process_zoom_rollover (event: MouseEvent): void 
{ 
    //trace("event.currentTarget : " + event.currentTarget.name );
    event.currentTarget.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate_Zoom);
}

//# mouse pointer is now move away from over any zoom icon.
function process_zoom_rollout (event: MouseEvent): void 
{ 
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate_Zoom);
}

function animate_Zoom (event:MouseEvent) : void 
{
    //# scale by PERCENTAGE (width or height / 100), then multiply by some SPEED amount
    if (event.currentTarget.name == "zoom_in") //increase width and height
    { pic.width += ((pic.width /100 ) * 1.75); pic.height += ((pic.height /100 ) * 1.75);  }

    if (event.currentTarget.name == "zoom_out") //decrease width and height
    { pic.width -= ((pic.width /100 ) * 1.75); pic.height -= ((pic.height /100 ) * 1.75);  }
}
```

Second example will update zoom via mouse clicks...

```
zoom_in.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, process_zoom_click);
zoom_out.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, process_zoom_click);

//# mouse pointer is placed over either zoom-in or zoom-out icon.
function process_zoom_click (event:MouseEvent) : void 
{ 
    //trace("event.currentTarget : " + event.currentTarget.name );
    if (event.currentTarget.name == "zoom_in") //increase width and height
    { pic.width += ((pic.width /100 ) * 1.75); pic.height += ((pic.height /100 ) * 1.75);  }

    if (event.currentTarget.name == "zoom_out") //decrease width and height
    { pic.width -= ((pic.width /100 ) * 1.75); pic.height -= ((pic.height /100 ) * 1.75);  }
}
```